# How to implement ontap() function in a custom navigation-drawer list items

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-layout

In my attempt to create a custom **Navigation Drawer** in Flutter, I am looking for how I can implement the **onTap()** method on the list items. I think I should be able to define the function and pass it into the _buildRow(Icons.person_pin, "Profile"), as an argument.
pls check my code below to understand what I actually mean

I simply want to respond to a click/tap event when the list menu are tap. in the default navigation drawer the is **onTap** attribute in the **ListTile** Widget.
That is

```
ListTile(
                  title: Text("Home"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
```

**Here is my code snippet**

> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> import 'package:payload/src/oval-right-clipper.dart';
>
> ```
> class AppEntryHomeAuthenticated extends StatelessWidget {
>   final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
>   final Color primary = Colors.white;
>   final Color active = Colors.grey.shade800;
>   final Color divider = Colors.grey.shade600;
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       key: _key,
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         elevation: 50.0,
>         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
>         centerTitle: true,
>         title: Text('PayLoad', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
>         actions: <Widget>[
>           Icon(Icons.settings),
>         ],
>         automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
>         leading: IconButton(
>           icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
>           onPressed: () {
>             _key.currentState.openDrawer();
>           },
>         ),
>       ),
>       drawer: _buildDrawer(),
>       body: SingleChildScrollView(),
>     );
>   }
>
>   _buildDrawer() {
>     return ClipPath(
>       clipper: OvalRightBorderClipper(),
>       child: Drawer(
>         child: Container(
>           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 40),
>           decoration: BoxDecoration(
>               color: primary, boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45)]),
>           width: 300,
>           child: SafeArea(
>             child: SingleChildScrollView(
>               child: Column(
>                 children: <Widget>[
>                   Container(
>                     alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
>                     child: IconButton(
>                       icon: Icon(
>                         Icons.power_settings_new,
>                         color: active,
>                       ),
>                       onPressed: () {},
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                   Container(
>                     height: 90,
>                     alignment: Alignment.center,
>                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                         shape: BoxShape.circle,
>                         gradient: LinearGradient(
>                             colors: [Colors.white10, Colors.white10])),
>                     child: CircleAvatar(
>                       child: Image.asset(
>                         "assets/images/logo.png",
>                         fit: BoxFit.contain,
>                       ),
>                       radius: 40,
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                   SizedBox(height: 5.0),
>                   Text(
>                     "PayLoad Mobile",
>                     //"PayLoad Wallet",
>                     style: TextStyle(
>                         color: active,
>                         fontSize: 18.0,
>                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
>                   ),
>                   //  Text(
>                   //    "@ray",
>                   //    style: TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 16.0),
>                   //  ),
>                   SizedBox(height: 30.0),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.home, "Home",),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.person_pin, "Profile"),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.save, "Saving Targets", showBadge: true),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.notifications, "Notifications",
>                       showBadge: false),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.settings, "Settings"),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.question_answer, "Feedback"),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.info_outline, "Help"),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                   _buildRow(Icons.share, "Share"),
>                   _buildDivider(),
>                 ],
>               ),
>             ),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
>
>   Divider _buildDivider() {
>     return Divider(
>       color: divider,
>     );
>   }
>
>   Widget _buildRow(IconData icon, String title, {bool showBadge = false}) {
>     final TextStyle tStyle = TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 16.0);
>     return Container(
>       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
>       child: Row(children: [
>         Icon(
>           icon,
>           color: active,
>         ),
>         SizedBox(width: 10.0),
>         Text(
>           title,
>           style: tStyle,
>         ),
>         Spacer(),
>         if (showBadge)
>           Material(
>             color: Colors.deepOrange,
>             elevation: 5.0,
>             shadowColor: Colors.red,
>             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
>             child: Container(
>               width: 25,
>               height: 25,
>               alignment: Alignment.center,
>               decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                 color: Colors.deepOrange,
>                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
>               ),
>               child: Text(
>                 "beta",
>                 style: TextStyle(
>                     color: Colors.white,
>                     fontSize: 12.0,
>                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
>               ),
>             ),
>           )
>       ]),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, please mark it as correct. This will help future users.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, you can wrap your items with a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and use its onTap method:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => myMethod(),
  child: Container(
    ...
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Works out well.
I only need to wrap the each list in Inkwell